# multiple vm detected error on an OpenGL example

Tags: lua, iup

Lua 5.3.5 is embedded in my application (written in C++) and I am using pre-built dynamic 32 bit Lua 5.3.5 libraries on Windows. In my application, I have a script editor which runs Lua scripts. I also use pre-built IUP 3.25 libraries (32 bit) to be able to run IUP scripts in Lua.

I have tested iup examples on [github](https://github.com/LuaDist/iup-examples/tree/master/examples/Lua). It seems most are running successful except [this example](https://github.com/LuaDist/iup-examples/blob/master/examples/Lua/glcanvas.wlua) which is on OpenGL. The problem happens with the line `require("luagl")`. When I delete the line, there is no error of "*multiple VMs detected*"; however, then the frame shows with no lines. I am confused as I can run examples like [this one](https://github.com/LuaDist/iup-examples/blob/master/examples/Lua/frame.wlua) with no problems.

I used Dependency walker and it seems all DLL libraries are pointing to Lua53.dll and for the [OpenGL example](https://github.com/LuaDist/iup-examples/blob/master/examples/Lua/glcanvas.wlua) the lines:

**1)** *require("iupluagl")*: Loads a) iupgl.dll, iuplua53.dll, lua53.dll and iup.dll

**2)** *require("luagl")*: Loads a) lua53.dll and luagl_base.dll

Exactly the same problem "multiple VMs detected" for exactly the same example happens with IUP 3.26 libraries.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Hi, this should not happen. I'll check it and return to you, but only next week. Thanks.

Comment: Does IUP libraries depend on lua53.dll?  Or does it contain its own Lua inside its DLL?  (Inspect UIP library DLL with something like "dependencywalker")

Comment: I think IUP depends on lua53.dll as it ships a lua53.dll file in the binaries. The problem doesn't happen with Lua5.2. By the way I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Do you have only one file "lua53.dll" on your computer?

Comment: In the folder, where I run the executable to start my C++ application, there is only one lua53.dll.

Comment: The problem is solved: 1) downloading "lua-5.3.4_Win32_dll15_lib" and 2) changing the internal lua engine and 3) using the lua53.dll that comes with it.

Comment: Hi, I just run that script using the latest IUP version (3.26) and Lua 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3, in 32 and 64 bits. There were no problems. I suggest you to download the "Tools Executables" package that contains some executables that you can run the same script on your system. For instance: iup-3.26-Lua53_Win32_bin.zip. If the script works, then compare that set with your own set. Maybe the luagl package you are using is outdated?
Anyway, just another path, since you already solved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the updates. I havent had the problem with Lua 5.2 or 5.3.4 but it was with Lua 5.3.5. Solved it with downgrading to Lua 5.3.4. Not sure but maybe I have done something wrong during the initial upgrade process.